# facebook: Post photo to timeline with restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to post photos to the user's page timeline with restfb.

My code is like this:

```
// Create parameters for the call
Collection<Parameter> params = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
params.add(Parameter.with("message", "My Message"));
Parameter postParamsArray[] = params.toArray(new Parameter[params.size()]);
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/4739627/2/stock-illustration-4739627-dreidel-game.jpg");
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish(facebookWallURL, FacebookType.class,BinaryAttachment.with("dreidel.jpg", url.openStream()), postParamsArray);
```

However, I see on the timeline only the text: My Message.

The user has the following permissions:

```
'manage_pages, publish_stream, create_event, photo_upload'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

facebookWallURL - looks like you're posting to wall. Try posting to the albums instead:

```
facebookURL = facebookPageId + "/photos";
publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish(facebookURL, FacebookType.class, ba, postParamsArray);
```

as written in this example:
(note **"me/videos"**)
http://restfb.com/

```
Publishing a Photo (see Graph API documentation)

// Publishing an image to a photo album is easy
// Just specify the image you'd like to upload and RestFB will handle it from there.

FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
  BinaryAttachment.with("cat.png", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.png")),
  Parameter.with("message", "Test cat"));

out.println("Published photo ID: " + publishPhotoResponse.getId());

// Publishing a video works the same way as uploading a photo.

facebookClient.publish("me/videos", FacebookType.class,
  BinaryAttachment.with("cat.mov", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.mov")),
  Parameter.with("message", "Test cat"));
```

Comment: @urlr it's not working for me.....showing exception                         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary attachment data cannot be null.

Comment: @sooraj this just means that your stream is actually null. the this piece of code getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.png") to a separate attribute and see it is probably null. Resolve your file loading and the code will work perfectly.