# How to upload images to facebook using Graph API

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me by suggesting on the way to upload images to facebook in Java using Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [restfb](http://restfb.com/) to do this.  It should greatly ease your learning curve.

There's an example using restfb to upload images to facebook here:  [facebook: Post photo to timeline with restfb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699834/facebook-post-photo-to-timeline-with-restfb)